# Sails.js When try post not work

Tags: sails.js

route.js

```
'/users': {
  controller: 'users',
  action: 'list'
}
```

controller.js

```
list: function (req, res) {
        return 'this work!';
    }
```

i try post request via postman and ajax form but not work

PD: i'm new with sails.js

Comment: please read the sails docs  http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/controllers/routing-to-controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the required `http verb` to each routes

```
'post /users': {
  controller: 'users',
  action: 'list'
}
```